# I can't see month view in basic react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-boilerplate, react-big-calendar

Hi I can't see month view even when it's displayed in react-dev tools. Week view works fine but month view doesn't displays anything. PFA the code below.

> Here is the week view image.

[image: week view works fine]

> Here is the month view image.

[image: Month view doesn't displays in DOM]

```
import localizer from 'react-big-calendar/lib/localizers/globalize';
import globalize from 'globalize';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import events from './events';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import './prism.less';

localizer(globalize);

const allViews = Object.keys(BigCalendar.views).map(k => 
BigCalendar.views[k])

export class EventDetailModal extends React.Component { // eslint-
disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

render() {
return (
<BigCalendar
{...this.props}
events={events}
views={allViews}
defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 1)}
/>
);
}
}

export default EventDetailModal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set a height value on a parent container? From their docs:

> It uses modern flexbox for layout making it super responsive and performant. Leaving most of the layout heavy lifting to the browser. **note**: The default styles use height: 100% which means your container must set an explicit height (feel free to adjust the styles to suit your specific needs).

([Source](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#api))

Answer (score 3):

Need to provide an explicit height to the calendar per the documentation.
eg.

```
.rbc-month-view {
      height: 100vh;
}
```

or

```
.rbc-calendar {
    min-height: 580px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your global css, and it should work

```
    .rbc-month-view {
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the width for the parent component.